# Jupyter opens a 'dead' notebook interface: cannot create a new one, or open an existing

Tags: python, ssh, jupyter

So after following all the instructions, the token finally worked, and I'm looking at this:

[image]

This is very embarrassing. I tried running an existing notebook:

```
jupyter notebook nbk.ipynb
```

with the same result. I also opened a new notebook within the notebook by starting a new Terminal, but it didn't work either.

UPDATE

The server uses Linux, on the local machine I use Windows.

The original:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Get the port address (8888) and the token

then, in Windows, in `cmd` run `ssh`:

```
ssh -N -L localhost:8887:localhost:8888 username@ip
```

Open the chrome tab on the local machine, navigate to `localhost:8887`, enter the token, get the screen below.

After @lww suggestion:

On the server, in Linux:

```
pip3 install virtualenv --user
mkdir awsm
cd awsm
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

Repeat the above. Same result. What did I do wrong?

Comment: please link to `the instructions`

Comment: @Gulzar I'm sorry do you mean the tag?

Comment: I mean you wrote that you followed some "instructions". Please post the link to that.

Comment: pls see the edit

Comment: `ssh user@serverip -L 8888:localhost:8888`  without -N switch because you need to execute commands later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so the problem seems to have been with the jupyter lab. I noticed jupyter is throwing an error:

```
Could not open static file ''
```

So after a bit of googling and printing out the `jupyter --version`:

```
    jupyter core     : 4.5.0
    jupyter-notebook : 6.0.0
    qtconsole        : 4.5.2
    ipython          : 7.7.0
    ipykernel        : 5.1.1
    jupyter client   : 5.3.1
    jupyter lab      : not installed
    nbconvert        : 5.5.0
    ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
    nbformat         : 4.4.0
    traitlets        : 4.3.2

Without virtualenv, I installed 

    pip3.5 install jupyterlab --user
    pip3.5 install tornado==5.0 --user
    pip3.5 install -U jupyter --user
```

Accessed the remote server from terminal:

```
ssh id@server.ip -L 8889:localhost:8889
```

Ran jupyter: `jupyter notebook --no-browser` and then opened the remote link on the local browser: `http://localhost:8889`

And it works!

Answer (score 1):

When ssh to remote server `-N` means  "Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports."
One possible problem is that you should not use -N switch first time at least least because you will need to execute some commands like creating virtual environment installing jupyter.

Example procedure: ssh from windows 10 machine to guest virtual machine ubuntu 20.04

Working from windows terminal:

```
c:\users\lww\desktop\>ssh tuv@192.168.1.99 -L 8888:localhost:8888
$ sudo pip3 install virtualenv --user
$ mkdir awsm && cd awsm
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install notebook
$ jupyter notebook
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: nope didn't work. venv dir didn't appear. Do I need to change anything in the way I open the link to the remote server?

Comment: Hi @Alex virtualenv must be installed `pip install virtualenv` on windows or `sudo apt install virtualenv` on ubuntu. Could you write what system do you work currently on?. There are small differences between Linux and windows installation. also what python version do you use that will be helpful. getting remote link you need to use `jupyter notebook --<IP> --<PORT> `   , on the console link will appear that you can copy and use locally.

Comment: Thanks Alex i read the edit. You can solve this by working from windows terminal alone.  ssh to your remote server from windows, first verify if virtualenv is installed `virtualenv  --version` (i am sure it is but just in case).  when you run `virtualenv venv`  venv directory appears, verify that it exists too.  then activate it `source venv/bin/activate`  then install jupyter `pip install notebook` then run `jupyter notebook --ip <your remote server IP>`  copy long URL link with token and  that is it. it will work on your local windows machine browser

Comment: didn't work unfortunately: when I run jupyter notebook from the same terminal, i get the same error; when I run jupyter notebook --ip http://127.0.0.1:8888/.... from a different terminal, I get ValueError: 'http://127.0.0.1:8889' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address

Comment: @Alex, sorry I couldn't help. hate to say it but "it works on my computer"

Comment: pls see my answer. Thanks for the help, it was very informative (+1)